# javascript reduce sum array with undefined values

Tags: javascript

I have this simple array with numbers:

```
var arr = [100,200,undefined,450,300];
```

I would like to use `reduce` for quickly summing up the values in that array like so...

```
var total = arr.reduce( function( s, v ){ return s += v } );
```

In `return` I am getting `NaN`.

Is there any way to make `reduce` to sum values in array with undefined values? like a flag or something... Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use a default value for [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values (`undefined`, `null`, `0`, `''`, and some more) with a [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()), like

```
v || 0
```

That means if `v` is a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value, than take that value, if not, then take zero.

```js
var arr = [100, 200, undefined, 450, 300],
    total = arr.reduce(function (s, v) { return s + (v || 0); }, 0);

console.log(total);
```

BTW,

```
s += v
   ^
```

is not necessary, because you do not use `s` anymore in the function. The returned value is the new value for `s` in the next loop. The variables of the callback are independent and they have their own scope.

---

- Based on the comments, you need to normalize the data, if various types of items are given, which are not wanted.

  - Filter unwanted parts,

    ```
    .filter(v => !isNaN(v))
    ```
  - convert wanted parts to the same type

    ```
    .map(Number)
    ```
- Then you need a function for folding the data, to get only a singel value out of two values, like an addition.

  ```
  function add(a, b) {
      return a + b;
  }
  ```
- This function is now used as callback for [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with an

  > **`initialValue`** (Optional)
  >
  > Value to use as the first argument to the first call of the `callback`. If no initial value is supplied, the first element in the array will be used. Calling `reduce()` on an empty array without an initial value is an error.

  ```
  result = array
      .filter(v => !isNaN(v))
      .map(Number)
      .reduce(add, 0);
  ```

Comment: @georg, right different question, different answer: arr.reduce((s, v) => isNaN(v) ? s : s + +v)

Comment: How about `[100,200,"300"]` then? ;))

Comment: Seriously, I'd compose here `.filter(!isNaN).map(Number).reduce(...)`

Comment: @HMR, good catch, a start value is necessary, if the check is only made for the second parameter of the callback and for an empty array.

Answer (score 3):

You could filter out the non numbers before you reduce your array.

This is not the most efficient way to reduce the list, but it is the most explicit where you are separating the functionality so you can easily follow the logic without needing to read through more complex logic.

```js
var arr = [100,200,undefined,450,300,'string'];

var total = arr
  .filter(function(x) { return typeof(x) === 'number'}) // remove any non numbers
  .reduce(function( s, v ){ return s + Number(v) }, 0);
  
console.log(
  total
)
```

Comment: Good thinking, function composition is the way to go. The `Number` cast is obviously superfluous...

Answer (score 2):

Just a ternary should do

```js
var arr = [100, 200, undefined, 450, 300];

var total = arr.reduce(function(s, v) {
return v ? s += v : s += 0
});

console.log(total);
```

Comment: You should pass the second argument (in this case 0) to reduce to prevent it from blowing up on empty array.

Comment: Second parameter to reduce would solve `[undefined].reduce(yourReducer)` returning undefined as well

Answer (score 1):

Try with `filter()`:

```js
var arr = [100,200,undefined,450,300];

var total = arr.filter(i=>i != undefined).reduce( function( s, v ){ 
    return s += v;
  }, 0);
  
console.log(total)
```

Comment: You should pass the second argument (in this case 0) to reduce to prevent it from blowing up on empty array.